# SQLAlchemy using the same session across threads in the same async function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

The question basically boils down to whether the following is safe, assuming there is a new SQLAlchemy session `s` being created everytime this function is invoked:

```
async def func(s: Session):
  loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
  await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_func, s)
  await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_other_func, s)
  ...
```

I'm thinking that it is safe because even though the session is used in (potentially) two different threads in the two `run_in_executor` calls, those two calls are not concurrent, since the second call won't be executed until the first one completes. This means the session is not accessed concurrently. Am I right in thinking that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a response from Mike Bayer himself (thanks again for the fast response!): https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5828. TLDR is that yes it is safe as long as the access is not concurrent.